# Lotus Notes 8 Client - Client will not reload after crash

Tags: crash, lotus-notes, reboot

Lotus Notes 8 Client crashes and the user is unable to restart the app without a reboot.  I see from the forums that programs such as zapnotes and notesnkill have existed for older versions of the client. Now that the Lotus Sandbox is closed and zapnotes is no longer available what else can be done to restart the client without a reboot?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can end each task manually (there may be a nlnotes.exe, nprocmon.exe, notes.exe, notes2.exe, nmailman.exe, and some others, just check your Lotus Notes Install - directory for all possible exes)
And you can download killnotes or NotesMedic from some sources, they will still work.

But the most secure way to end all processes loaded by Lotus Notes is to use the internal nsd. Just create a new shortcut: navigate to the Lotus\Notes and select nsd.exe. Then enter -kill as a parameter.

The link then looks like: C:\Program Files\Lotus\Notes\nsd.exe -kill
Of course you can also simply use a cmd- box or any other way to run this command.

This will kill all open processes and let you start Lotus Notes without a reboot necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There is normally a zombie process still running on your computer that prevents Notes from restarting.  If you kill this process, you can restart Notes without rebooting. Assuming you are using Windows right-click the start bar and choose *Task Manager*. In the *Processes* tab you will find a program called *notes.exe* - select this and choose *End Process*.

NB The process may have different but similar names nearby in the list - look for *lnotes.exe* also.  I am not on my Windows machine so I can't double check the filenames - I'll edit this answer soon and give a complete list.